# Why does Typescript not narrow generic union type components when they get eliminated by type guards?

Tags: typescript

Given the following type definitions and function implementations:

```
interface WithNumber {
  foo: number;
}

interface WithString {
  bar: string;
}

type MyType = WithNumber | WithString;

interface Parameter<C extends MyType = MyType> {
  container: C
} 

function isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg: Parameter): arg is Parameter<WithNumber> {
  return typeof (arg.container as WithNumber).foo === "number";
}

function test(arg: Parameter<WithNumber | WithString>) {
  if (isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg)) {
    arg.container.foo;
    return;
  }
  /*
   * Error:
   *   Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'MyType'.
   *     Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'WithNumber'.
   */
  arg.container.bar;
}
```

Why does Typescript not narrow down the type of `arg` below the if-block guarded with a type guard? In my opinion, it is impossible that arg will be something else than a `Parameter<WithString>`. Typescript however still thinks that it is a `Parameter<WithNumber | WithString>` and thus throws an error when trying to access `arg.container.bar`.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20WithNumber%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WithString%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MyType%20%3D%20WithNumber%20%7C%20WithString%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Parameter%3CC%20extends%20MyType%20%3D%20MyType%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20container%3A%20C%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg%3A%20Parameter)%3A%20arg%20is%20Parameter%3CWithNumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20typeof%20(arg.container%20as%20WithNumber).foo%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(arg%3A%20Parameter%3CWithNumber%20%7C%20WithString%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arg.container.foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20arg.container.bar%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to find the apropriate documentation but I can't. My understanding of the way type guards work with `if` statements is that the type on the `then` branch is excluded form a union type on the `else` branch. It does not go in depth on a type to see what can be excluded. Your parameter is a generic type with a union type as a generic parameter, so nothing will be excluded on `else` branch.

A simple work around would be to make the argument a union type:

```
function isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg: Parameter): arg is Parameter<WithNumber> {
    return typeof (arg.container as WithNumber).foo === "number";
}

function test(arg: Parameter<WithNumber> | Parameter<WithString>) {
    if (isParameterWithNumberContainer(arg)) {
        arg.container.foo;
        return;
    }
    arg.container.bar;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You only need to change the ` test(arg: ParameterWithContainer<WithNumberContainer> | ParameterWithContainer<WithStringContainer>)` line. The custom type guard can still use `Parameter`, allowing it to be used broadly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawlessly, even though it takes a bit more effort. Maybe one day TS will be able to deal with this even when the union type is used as a generic parameter, until then a bit more code seems necessary.